# How to label text with equation number?

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm trying to put equation numbers next to text as if said text was an equation. If I use `\text{}` in an `align*` environment, it typesets the text right-aligned and the whole environment centered, but that's not what I want. I would like the text to look like in an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment (for example, indented), but still with an equation number behind it. And that equation number should come from the regular equation number "pool".

Ideally, it would look like this:

```
We have to make sure that:
  A is very b,             (1)
  A is not c.              (2)
```

How can I write this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way (taken some code from  [Input manually a number into `\eqref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113141/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqnum}{\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{\tagform@{\theequation}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{myeqn1}
\end{equation}
See~\eqref{myeqn1}. Also
\begin{itemize}
  \item $A$ is very~$b$, \eqnum\label{myeqn2}
  \item $A$ is not~$c$. \eqnum\label{myeqn3}
\end{itemize}
There is also~\eqref{myeqn2} and~\eqref{myeqn3}.
\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides `\eqnum` which inserts the equation number using the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) `\eqref` way. A subsequent `\label` makes one able to reference it. Of course, the print-and`\label` technique could be combined, if needed:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqlab}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}\textup{\tagform@{\theequation}}}
\makeatother
```

which allows one to use `\eqlab{<label>}`.

For flushed-right equation numbering, use the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\eqnum}{\leavevmode\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{\tagform@{\theequation}}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The flushed right solution is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

This may be a little hack-ish …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{equationate}{%
 \itemize
 \let\orig@item\item
 \def\item{\orig@item[]\refstepcounter{equation}\def\item{\hfill(\theequation)\orig@item[]\refstepcounter{equation}}}
}{%
 \hfill(\theequation)%
 \enditemize
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
We have to make sure that:
\begin{equationate}
 \item A is very b,
 \item A is not c.
\end{equationate}
Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
        We have to make sure that:
    \begin{equation}
        \text{A is very b,}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \text{A is not c.}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: See my original question. I didn't want the centering.

Comment: This is helpful in my situation, thanks :)