# Mixing itemize with multi-line math displays

Tags: itemize

I have a list of equations that I want to enumerate using itemize.  The equations should also be numbered equations.  This is no problem if those equations fit onto one line -- I just typeset them between dollar signs (and use the macro from the first answer to [How to label text with equation number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114113/how-to-label-text-with-equation-number) to number things).  The problem arises when some of the equations take multiple lines.  I want to use \begin{split} to split them up.  The problem is that using \begin{equation} and \begin{split} forces everything to be on a new line, and I want this stuff to appear on the line with the big dot from itemize.  It won't let me use split in in-line math.  How can I get this to work?

EDIT : Here is an example to illustrate what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \[\begin{split}
7x+2y = &3z+7w\\
        &+23654
\end{split}\]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The problem with the above is two-fold : first, the math is on a separate line from the big dot, and second it is centered.  I ignored the numbering at this point to make things easier to understand.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Added something.  Let me know if it is unclear what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t] 
        7x+2y &=3z+7w \\
              &\phantom{=}+23654   
       \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned]

Comment: `\displaystyle` is unneeded. However I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate.