# Flush items to the right in enumerate, itemize, etc

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

is there some way to make the items in `enumerate`, `itemize`, and similar environments right aligned instead of left aligned. I'm thinking sort of like what the `equation` environment does automatically numbering equations, but which would work the same way for other kinds of propositions. Something like this:

A=B, according the ...    (1)

B=C, since every ...      (2)

(1) & (2) --> A=C         (3)

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal example (compilable document showing the issue you want help with). Some clarification would also be helpful. Should the numbers be aligned on the right? In your sample output, they are not. Should the content be aligned on the left as in your sample? Neither of those applies to `equation` so it is not very clear which of what your want.

Comment: I've retagged this because you don't mention **enumitem** in your question. If you use it in the code you post, by all means add it back.

Comment: check [this out](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114113/how-to-label-text-with-equation-number)

Comment: potential duplicate?  [How to label text with equation number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114113/579)